# Create an API with Mulesoft for OAuth2 PING to generate the token

Tags: mulesoft

I want to create an API with Mulesoft to be able to obtain the token from calling the OAuth2 Ping provider.

Comment: Do you mean you need to implement an API with a Mule runtime application, or an API proxy with policies? Please provide more details on the OAuth provider and what the application should be doing.

Comment: @aled Hi, I want to implement it in Mule runtime app. The OAuth provider is Ping. I have the call postman, so if you think it can help I can paste it here. Thanks

Comment: Providing all the details should be part of the question. See Kindly read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for guidance on how to make a good question. Otherwise the question may go unanswered or even closed because of lack of focus or details.

Comment: The basic idea is that we want to create an API with Mule that will be easy to use to obtain the authorization token, just click send and receive the token that will be used for authorization in API's that have the OAuth2 provider.
Here you can see the settings from Postman for obtaining the token:
https://imgur.com/a/rX3q30M
And the request is to create a new API that will do the call to take the token.
@aled